# How costly is to find millions of large prime numbers for RSA?

Tags: rsa, prime-numbers, number-theory

Consider I need to assign a large distinct prime number to each element in a large set. This must be deterministic so the function always gives me the same prime to the same value.

1. What is the most efficient way to do this (if there is any).
2. Would this function work if I need to find millions of prime number to assign them to the set elements.

Btw.: With “large prime number”, I mean the one is usually considered for RSA.

Comment: Note: I'm aware of the other posts, but they consider only a couple of large prime numbers.

Comment: Mind if I ask about the problem you're solving?  If you're trying to generate a large number of distinct RSA keys, well, there're actually faster approaches...

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/963506/oblivious-subset-computation

Comment: Do you require that it is hard to guess the primes, in particular with knowledge of some of the others? $\;$ Also, is maximum efficiency thought for generating all the primes, or for generating a particular one? $\;$ I ask because we know algorithms that generate $n$ related primes with significantly lower cost than $n$ times the cost of generating one.

Comment: @fgrieu: one requirement is that the product of two of those primes be hard to factor.  The problem with those known algorithms is that they generate primes which are numerically close to each other, which means that their product may be easy to factor (say, via Fermat factorization)

Comment: @fgrieu What if we run these efficient algorithms many times then pick a subset of random primes each time? I'm not sure if we can make it deterministic.

Comment: @poncho: That's a bit of a strange requirement given that knowledge of $p_1\cdot p_2$, and $p_1\cdot p_3$, it will be trivial to find $p_1$ (by GCD), then $p_2$ and $p_3$. $\,$ Sieve algorithms can be extended to generate primes far apart from each others; that's standard practice with regular spacing, and I do not rule out that it can be done with more haphazard spacing.

Comment: @fgrieu I'll be very pleased if you could have look at the link I put in the comment. That is the actual problem I try to solve.

Comment: @user153465: turning a randomized algorithm into a deterministic one is standard practice in crypto: we'll use a CSPRNG seeded with a secret and e.g. the index of the element to which the prime is associated. $\;$ Doing this and using a standard algorithm for RSA primes would be an easy way to solve your problem (as in the present question), save for the _most efficient_ requirement. A standard desktop CPU would generate some hundred 1024-bit primes per second, I guess. $\;$ I'll read and ponder the math.se question.

Comment: @fgrieu Could you explain a bit more clear please.

Comment: @fgrieu: you're right; I was worried that if the step you take between sieved elements was too small, the discovered primes would be too close.  However, if you're looking for primes for this purpose, you'd select a step of circa $2^{900}$ (say) for 1024 bit primes; the resulting primes would have plenty of spread.  (To user153465): Doing this would mean that if someone found two primes, factoring the rest would be a lot easier; that's why fgrieu asked if that would be a problem

Comment: @user153465: Additional questions: in your actual problem, do you require that the procedure mapping each element to a prime be public (that is, does not require knowledge of a secret)? If yes, the CSPRNG technique can't use a secret key; and it will always be possible to determine if a guess of elements in the set is right. $\;$ Also, can we assimilate an element to a moderate non-negative integer (say, less than $2^{128}$)?

Comment: @fgrieu If there is no way to make it public I'd go for the private one, then the secret can be shared between different users. for you latter question, I don't understand what you mean by "an element".

Comment: @user153465: by _an element_ I mean precisely what you mean with _each element (in a large set)_ in the text of the present question. $\;$ In the math.se question that seems to be a small non-negative integers, but if elements in the present question where actually books in html form, that's another thing.

Comment: @fgrieu it is a set element, so it could be a large positive value. Note that each element is a root of polynomial thus if these elements are too blarge I would have problem with polynomial interpolation.

Comment: @fgrieu Do you have any suggestion about the problem Im trying to solve?

Comment: OP: Are you implementing a [Honey Encryption](http://www.arijuels.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/HoneyEncryptionpre.pdf) scheme for RSA secret keys?

Comment: @pg1989 No, I've put the like of its application in comment.

Comment: I suggest you calculate a sha256 of you set value, and then using miller-rabin + increment, find the first prime following that hash value.

Comment: @WillemHengeveld what if two values have the close hash values so both are going to be mapped to the same prime. Am I right?

Comment: @fgrieu That is why I've put that question in math.se not in crypto.se, the other asked me what problem I'm considering to solve and I put that link. Again as it is "OBVIOUS" the question in crypto.se is not exactly about math rather the feasibility of finding some large prime numbers.

Comment: @user153465: after fixing the fact that 256-bit primes are too small (you need at least SHA-512 to get primes of size of cryptographic interest w.r.t. the RSA problem), what you are fearing when applying Willem Hengeveld's idea is so unlikely that it needs not be considered in practice (odds of a computer failure or oblivion by a comet are much higher); and if you had been looking for a mathematically exact solution (I understand that you are not), crypto.se would have been the wrong place [reposted with correction]

Comment: @fgrieu Cool, Got it now.

Comment: @Willem Hengeveld: issues with your idea: $\;$ A) SHA-256 is not wide enough. That's easily fixed with a CSPRNG or [KDF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key_derivation_function) $\;$ B) The primes generated are distinguishable from random ones, for the expected gap from such prime to the immediately lower prime is higher. That can be fixed by incrementing by a pseudo-randomly chosen step about (say) 100 times the number of bits in the prime. $\;$ C) This is relatively slow; at the very least, sieving the prime candidates will speed-up things many-fold. $\;$ All this is sometime practiced for RSA.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is doable.  Here is a construction, built out of several basic primitives:

- Let $R$ be a randomized  primality generation algorithm; there are many of them.

  It uses randomness, so let's make the bits of randomness it uses explicit as input: $R(c)$ is the output it produces, when given a random number generator that outputs the random bits $c$.
- Let $G$ be a cryptographically secure pseudorandom generator: something that stretches a short seed (key) to a long pseudorandom output.  You could use AES in CTR mode, or any stream cipher, for this.
- Let $H$ be a cryptographic hash function, e.g., SHA256.

Now, to element $x$, you can assign the prime number $R(G(H(x)))$ to $x$.  It's as simple as that.

This is a deterministic algorithm that will assign a prime to each element, and always assign the same prime to each possible element.  Also, if you generate primes from a large enough range, then the primes will almost surely be distinct.  For instance, if you generate 256-bit primes, then by the birthday paradox, it is essentially guaranteed that all the primes will be distinct (the chances that two different elements $x,x'$ is exponentially small, and negligible in practice).

Comment: Thanks for your very clear explanation. I'm wondering why cannot we use $x$ as the input of $G()$, so we could eliminate $H()$.

Comment: @user153465, that's because pseudorandom generators require their seed to be uniformly distributed.  The way to extract the entropy in a value and make it look uniformly distributed is to use a hash function.  Justifying that would probably require some non-trivial cryptographic knowledge (e.g., the random oracle model, definitions of security of a PRG, and so on).  Or, you can just trust me that this is a competently engineered cryptographic construction.